# looking for a way to actively stop the scrolling of a ScrollView in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The question is difficult to understand due to machine translation. Sorry.

I am looking for a way to actively stop the scrolling of a ScrollView in Flutter.

The action is
Scroll state -> multiple touches -> idle scrolling
I'm thinking of a flow like this.

The Listener widget is already able to acquire multiple touches
I can also get the scrolling state with NotificationListener, but I am not able to stop it from here.
but we are not able to stop it from here.

In the ScrollPosition documentation
I have confirmed that there is a method called beginActivity(ScrollActivity? newActivity), but I am not sure how to implement this method.
I am not sure how to implement this method.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me solve this problem.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
    onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollNotification) {

      if(_touchCount >= 2)
      {
        setState(() {
            //We plan to include a scroll stop process in this.
        });
      }

      return true;
    },
    child: Listener(
      onPointerDown: incrementEnter,
      onPointerUp: incrementExit,
      onPointerCancel: incrementExit,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            
          ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this works, but maybe you can try switching the physics of your list view to NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() when you register multiple touches.

Comment: I tried it, but when I entered the scrolling state and switched to it, the scrolling did not stop and remained in the same state of operation.
I was able to prevent it from scrolling again.

Comment: check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPositionWithSingleContext/goIdle.html - btw on the bottom you can see how it is implemented

Comment: I was aware of this function itself.
However, this class does not exist in the parameters of ScrollController, and it was unclear how to use it.
If there is a way to tie it to ScrollController, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

Comment: it is `ScrollController.position`

Comment: The position seems to be ScrollPosition class and not ScrollPositionWithSingleContext class.

Comment: `print(controller.position.runtimeType)`

Comment: Thanks.I wrote it like this, but I got a StackOverFlow error.
Is there any mistake in the description?
I wrote it like this, but I got a StackOverFlow error.
Is there any mistake in the description?`var position = scrollContoroller.position as ScrollPositionWithSingleContext;
 position.goIdle();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to create a [`ScrollController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html) which should be owned by `State` and passed into your `SingleChildScrollView`.

Subclass `ScrollController` and add a method to call or a member to set  when your touch count threshold is met to tell the controller to stop. By stop I mean override [`createScrollPosition`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController/createScrollPosition.html) and return the old position if that stop flag is true otherwise have the override return `super.createScrollPosition`.

---

Just to be clear, listening to the `ScrollNotification` and `setState` is unnecessary. All the logic should be in the scroll controller.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I understand what you are talking about, but could you please describe the specific code?

I can assume that it would be something like this, but...
I am not sure how to handle the arguments to be put in when overriding CreatePosition, so could you please tell me?